# Looking for a keyboard that can run macros without installing software

Tags: memory, keyboards

I'm looking for a keyboard that can execute macros stored in onboard memory without installing any drivers or software.  It's fine if software is required to set them up, but they need to be used on a computer with very few permissions. Anyone have any recommendations?  Trying to keep it under $100 if possible.

If I can make the macro without having to record actual keystrokes, that would be a bonus.

Comment: What kind of 'macro'? What platform?

Comment: If you're handy with C programming and Arduino stuff there is a whole community around custom keyboard firmware: [QMK](https://qmk.fm/). This chipset is usually used in those DIY mechanical keyboard kits but you can find lots of pre-assembled products online using this firmware. You can compile your own firmware that can run any kind of macro you can imagine from any key input.

Comment: @tetsujin I just need a single keypress to output a bunch of text.  The platform will be Windows, but it needs to act as just a USB keyboard so the platform shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Sharkoon Skiller SKG5 stores macro's and can run them without Sharkoon software. Although you do need the Sharkoon software to set them up, I think it flashes it to the keyboard, so it can also be used on other computers. It is also avalible in AZERTY and QWERTY layouts.

About price, I don't know the price now, but when I bought mine, it was €40.

(BTW I cannot test anymore if you can run the macro's without software, the Sharkoon software only runs on Windows and I don't use Windows anymore)

Comment: Presumably, any macros stored would only be any use on the platform they were originally written for anyway. For instance, `open /Applications/Mail` wouldn't do a thing on Windows, even if it worked on Mac, nor `start  "c:\windows\system32" notepad.exe` be the slightest use anywhere else.

Comment: That is true, I used to use an open chrome macro on Windows to test out this gimmick, but it didn't work on Linux. I think my Javascript logging macro still works though, although I forgot which key and state it is in...